# The Range.getValue method is widely used by the script an execution hint(the light bulb in the menu)

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

Hello I wrote a script that complets several Google Docs tables with values from different columns in a Spreadsheet.
I declared the columns variables : (8 in total)

```
var colonne_nom_de_projet = 3
var colonne_code_de_projet = 1
var colonne_chef_de_projet = 7
var colonne_service_pilote_de_projet = 8
var colonne_autres_services_projet = 11
var colonne_typede_projet = 10
var colonne_perimetre__projet  = 12
var colonne_date_de_projet = 18
```

and `var NUMERO_COLONNE_2019 = 2;` 
so the name of the project is in the third column ... and the date in 18 column and I want to create a doc only if I have yes in the second columnAfter that I started to complete my Google Doc table with this values

```
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
      var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues(); 

      var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
      Logger.log('targetFolder name: ' + targetFolder.getName());

      var numRows=sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var nombre_projets_2019 = 0 ;
      // à partir de 2 car la première ligne ne nous interesse pas
      for(n=2;n<=data.length;++n) {
          if (sheet.getRange(n,NUMERO_COLONNE_2019).getValue() == 'yes'){
 if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE && child.asTable().getNumRows() >= 8)
            {
         child.asTable().getCell(0, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_nom_de_projet).getValue() );
                      child.asTable().getCell(1, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_code_de_projet).getValue() )  ;
                      child.asTable().getCell(2, k).editAsText().setText(sheet.getRange(n,colonne_chef_de_projet).getValue())  ;
                      child.asTable().getCell(3, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_service_pilote_de_projet).getValue() )  ;
                      child.asTable().getCell(4, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_autres_services_projet).getValue() )  ;
                      child.asTable().getCell(5, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_typede_projet).getValue() )  ;
                      child.asTable().getCell(6, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_perimetre__projet).getValue() )  ;
                      child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_date_de_projet).getValue() )  ;
```

and it works but I have a message and an execution hint(the light bulb in the menu)

> "The Range.getValue method is widely used by the script.CollapseFile:
>   Code Line: 75The script uses a method that is considered expensive.
>   Each invocation generates a long-term call to a remote server. This
>   can have a critical impact on script execution time, especially on
>   large data. If the script has a performance problem, we recommend that
>   you use another method, such as Range.getValues ()." If you have any ideas it will be great ^^^^ because line 75 corresponds to

`if (sheet.getRange(n,NUMERO_COLONNE_2019).getValue() == 'yes')`

Edit edit : this is my very very slow code 4 minutes

```js
    function create_Google_Docs_2019_0() {
      
      var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID).getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);
      var numRows = sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var data = sheet.getRange(1,1,numRows,lastColumn).getValues()
    
      
      var targetFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
      Logger.log('targetFolder name: ' + targetFolder.getName());
      
      var numRows=sheet.getLastRow();
      var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();
      var nombre_projets_2019 = 0 ;
      
      
      // à partir de 2 car la première ligne ne nous interesse pas
       for(n=1;n < data.length;n++) {
        
        //verifier si c'est une projet 2019 >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>  ici on fait notre travail 
         if ( data[n][1] == 'o'){
          nombre_projets_2019 = nombre_projets_2019  + 1;
          var nom_projet = data[n][2];
           
          //var nom_document = 'Projet ' + nom_projet ;
          var nom_document = nom_projet ;
          /** Recherche si dans folder il y a déjà ce fichier avec ce nom on va l'actualiser avec les données changés**/
          
          if( checkFile_in_a_Folder(nom_document,targetFolder) == 1){
            //on ajoute le fichier dans le repertoire courant targetFolder
            Logger.log('On va réecrire le ficher / overwrite le ficher ');
          } 
          else
          {
            Logger.log('On va le créer avec les données qu on a dans le tableau ');
            //Make a copy of the template file
            var documentId = DriveApp.getFileById(TEMPLATE_DOC_ID).makeCopy().getId();
            
            //Rename the copied file
            var name = DriveApp.getFileById(documentId).setName(nom_document);
            var body = DocumentApp.openById(documentId).getBody();
            if(body)
            {
              var ok = 0;       //pour l'instant il n'y a pas de tableau
              var numChildren=body.getNumChildren();
              var i=0;
              //tant qu'on n'a pas du tableau on va parcourir
              while(ok ==0 && i<numChildren)
              {
                var child=body.getChild(i);
                /** ============On est concerné par le premier tableau seulement qui a au plus 8 lignes d'information ================**/
                Logger.log('Le type dans la boucle  ' + child.getType());
                //on a trouvé un tableau
                if(child.getType()==DocumentApp.ElementType.TABLE && child.asTable().getNumRows() >= 8)
                {
                  //on a trouve notre premier tableau
                  ok=1;   
                  
                  
                  var numrows = child.asTable().getNumRows();
                  Logger.log('Le nombre de lignes dans notre Google Doc  ' + numrows);
                  
                  var insertion_position  = n ;
                  Logger.log('Position pour inserer dans le spreadsheet  ' + insertion_position);
                  
                  var k = 1;
                  child.asTable().getCell(0, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_nom_de_projet-1]);
                  child.asTable().getCell(1, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_code_de_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(2, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_chef_de_projet-1])  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(3, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_service_pilote_de_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(4, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_autres_services_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(5, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_typede_projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(6, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_perimetre__projet-1] )  ;
                  child.asTable().getCell(7, k).editAsText().setText( data[n][colonne_date_de_projet-1] )  ;
                }
                i++;
              }
            }
          } 
        }
        Logger.log('Nombre de projets 2019 ' +  nombre_projets_2019 );
      }
    }
```

it's a project so that by searching in the second column for 'o' (oui in French) means that the project will be in 2019 so i will get the information from several columns i want(name project,date,chef de project...) and then put this information in a Google Doc Table created using a Template with makecopy() with 8 rows and 2 columns so all the information will be put in the second colum.In fact my code is very slow and if you have any ideas to improuve it will be great because it does the work in about 4 min

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use range.getValues() to get the values in an array (single call to API), instead of using .getValue() multiple times (multiple calls, 'considered expensive').

Instead of:

```
for(n=2;n<=data.length;++n) {
    child.asTable().getCell(0, k).editAsText().setText( sheet.getRange(n,colonne_nom_de_projet).getValue() );
    child.asTable().getCell(2, k).editAsText().setText(sheet.getRange(n,colonne_chef_de_projet).getValue())  ;

    //etc.
```

Use:

```
var values = sheet.getRange(0,0,20,20).getValues() //or whatever the range is
for(n=2;n<=data.length;++n) {
    child.asTable().getCell(0, k).editAsText().setText( values[n][colonne_nom_de_projet]) );
    child.asTable().getCell(2, k).editAsText().setText(values[n][colonne_chef_de_projet]))  ;
    //etc.
```

Something like that, you get the idea.

Comment: I've edited the post  in fact it's a project so that by  searching in the second column for 'o' (oui in French) means that the project will be in 2019 so i will get the information from several columns i want(name project,date,chef de project...) and then put this information in a Google Doc Table created using a Template with makecopy() with 8 rows and 2 columns so all the information will be put in the second colum.In fact my code is very slow and if you have any ideas to improuve it will be great because it does the work in about 4 min

Comment: Yes, use the same technique to edit the Google Doc Table, using a 2 dim array. See here:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/table
"When creating a Table that contains a large number of rows or cells, consider building it from a string array, as shown in the following example."
 var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
 // Create a two-dimensional array containing the cell contents.
 var cells = [
   ['Row 1, Cell 1', 'Row 1, Cell 2'],
   ['Row 2, Cell 1', 'Row 2, Cell 2']
 ];
 // Build a table from the array.
 body.appendTable(cells);

Comment: Thanks.  I don't create the table in the Google Doc I get it from the Template so i search for the first children with 8 or more rows and the put the value in the right the big problem comes also from the sheet but I don't get it